# Which alternative is correct , "on another day" or "at another day"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm writting a text and I'm not sure which preposition to use, "on another day" or "at another day".

The context is as follows:

"the device can be disassembled and the measurements are made on/at another day"

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On another day, or "at a later date" work and seem to fit your meaning here.

Comment: Hello, andre. Please check at the Help Center about how to write a good answer, and what sort of questions are considered inappropriate on ELU (and hence better left unanswered, so as not to send mixed messages to the user-base).